# Understanding inf-sup conditions for classical saddle point problems

Tags: finite-element, navier-stokes, saddlepoint

I'm studying the inf-sup conditions for saddle point problems. I'm referring to the usual one $$\begin{cases}Au + B^t p = f \\Bu=g \end{cases}$$ In the book I'm using (*Ern - Guermond: Theory and practice of FEM*) they say (pg. 100)

> The problem is well posed iff
>
> - $$ \exists \alpha >0: \inf_{u \in \ker(B)} \sup_{v \in \ker(B)} \frac{a(u,v)}{||u||_X ||v||_X} \geq \alpha$$
> - $$\forall v \in \ker(B), \forall u \in \ker(B), a(u,v)=0 \implies v=0$$
>   [... and then we have also the inf-sup on $B$, which is not a problem for me right now]

I understand how they derive them, but then, looking at my lecture notes, my professor replaced the second condition with **another inf-sup**

$$ \exists \alpha >0: \inf_{v \in \ker(B)} \sup_{u \in \ker(B)} \frac{a(u,v)}{||u||_X ||v||_X} \geq \alpha$$

I've searched in lots of books and lecuture notes, but I still cannot understand why this one above is equivalent to the second condition. In particular, it's clear to me that the last "inf-sup" must be strictly greater than $0$, but **I don't see why the constant $\alpha$ must be the same**.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think they're equivalent (in infinite dimensions), although the latter implies the former -- it's a sort of "quantitative injectivity". To see this, you can rearrange (estimating for fixed $u$ the $\inf$ over all $v$ by an arbitrary one and using the definition of the operator norm) to $\|A^*v\|\geq \alpha\|v\|$, which clearly implies the desired injectivity.

Comment: Just to be sure I understood your comment properly: if I rewrite the latter as $$ (\star) \inf_{v \in X} \frac{||A^* v||_{\ker(B)'}}{||v||} \geq \alpha > 0 $$ then $\ker(A^*)$ must be $\{0\}$ only, because $\star$ is $0$ only if $\ker(A^*)$ is not trivial. Indeed $\ker{A^*} = \{0\}$ is precisely the second condition of theorem. Is this what you had in mind? @ChristianClason

Comment: close enough -- I meant that (estimating the $\inf$ by some $w$ from above to make it clearer) this inequality shows that $\|A^*w\|=0$ implies that $\|w\|=0$, which  is exactly injectivity.

Comment: Uh yes, because if you rearrange the inf-sup with $||A^* w|| \geq \alpha ||w||$ then  indeed if $Av = Aw$ you got $0=||A(v-w)|| \geq \alpha ||v-w||$ which clearly implies $v = w$. @ChristianClason I think I got it now, right?

Comment: Yep, that's a perfectly valid way of putting it!

Comment: @ChristianClason I've just seen those lecture notes (https://www.mathsim.eu/~gkanscha/notes/mixed.pdf)  and if you look at page 33/34 the two inf sups are again with the same constant (it's called $\gamma$ there). I really can't see how he can derive the second inf-sup

Comment: I don't see where he claims that these are equivalent. Assumption (2.3.4) is the classical ellipticity condition (for the Lax--Milgram Theorem) that is sufficient but not necessary for invertibility of $A$ on $\mathrm{ker}(B)$. I also don't think the "if and only if" in Theorem 2.3.2 is correct.

Comment: @ChristianClason Uhm, but I'm referring to Corollary 2.2.13 and Theorem 2.2.15. In 2.2.13 he has only one inf-sup, and in 2.2.15 he writes the two inf-sups but with the same constant. Is there a way to show that the constants are the same? From the way he wrotes it seems that it's a "simple" consequence of closed range thm

Comment: (These are not on page 33/34.) Again, be careful distinguishing "if" and "if and only if". The claims are all correct but (slightly) different. Corollary 2.2.13 treats well-posedness of $A^*w=F$, while Theorem 2.2.15 that of $Av=F$. There's no reason that the constants _have_ to be the same; that's just convenience (and obviously true if $a$ is symmetric).

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing that out. However, I think I finally understood when the constants are the same: we need to set the problem in Hilbert spaces, while here I was considering only Banach operators. The reason is essentially in the following *Theorem*: $$A: V \rightarrow W'$$ with $V$ and $W$ Banach spaces. If
for every $w \in Im(A)$ there exists $v_{w} \in V$ such that $A_{v_w} = w$ and $$||Av_{w}||_{W'} \geq \alpha ||w||_V$$ **then**
$$||A^* w||_{V'} \geq \alpha ||w||_{W}$$. They're equivalent if $W$ is reflexive."

Comment: But if I set my problem in Hilbert spaces, then they're reflexive by Riesz theorem, and hence that equivalence provides me the two inf-sups conditions, by rearranging the two inequalities in the statement. Do you agree? @ChristianClason